# org-mode highlighting using minted for latex and htmlize for html

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, org-mode, pygments, htmlize.el

I'm trying to rewrite some document from latex in org-mode.

What I would like is the code to be highlighted in the exported latex/pdf and html.
For latex/pdf I'm using pygments and for html htmlize.el.

I have the following code fragment. If I choose the name "asm", highlighting works for html (htmlize.el) but not for pygments (because it doesn't recognize "asm"). If I change it to "nasm", it works for pygments but not for htmlize.el. How to solve this?

```
#+begin_src asm
    mov cx,3

    loopstart:
       do stuff
       dec cx
       jnz loopstart
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can patch the file `_mapping.py` in `../pygments/lexers/`, line 193:

```
'NasmLexer': ('pygments.lexers.asm', 'NASM', ('nasm','asm'), ('*.asm', '*.ASM'), ('text/x-nasm',)),
```

`('nasm',)` becomes `('nasm','asm')`

It can help: `locate _mapping.py`, don't remember to delete the old pyc: `sudo rm _mapping.pyc`, optionally: `sudo python  -c "import py_compile;py_compile.compile('_mapping.py')"`